# PANIC in default formatting with Go's log package

Tags: logging, formatting, go

When logging in Go with `log.Println`, I frequently get

```
2012/05/13 16:45:50 evaluating %v(PANIC=3)
```

I'm not sure how to determine what I've done wrong, I assume that somewhere `fmt.Println` has caught a panic generated by one of my own `Stringer` interface implementations, so as not to crash my program due to logging failure.

How do I work out what's going on? Why am I getting this erroneous message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there is a panic in a `String` method. But it has nothing to do with the `log` package. `Println` uses `%v`, and `%v` means running `String` method. Having a panic in the `String` method invokes [`catchPanic`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/print.go#L630). Here in your output `3` is the value of your panic.

Comment: Cheers. With a debugger attached, the process is interrupted at the point the panic is thrown, and it is as you described.

Answer (score 1):

W/o the code to inspect it's hard to say. To debug it, perhaps try replacing `log.Println("evaluating", foo)` with `log.Printf("evaluating %#v\n", foo)`. It works a bit differently:

```
package main

import "log"

type t int

func (t) String() string {
    panic(3)
}

func main() {
    var v t = 42
    log.Println("evaluating", v)
    log.Printf("evaluating %#v\n", v)
}
```

---

```
$ go run main.go
2012/05/13 11:19:49 evaluating %v(PANIC=3)
2012/05/13 11:19:49 evaluating 42
$
```