# Go Println suppressing stack-trace for panic in String()

Tags: go

In the code below, the invalid index access `x[10]` results in a panic. However, the panic message produced doesn't show the stack-trace of the error - rather, it looks like this: `%!v(PANIC=String method: runtime error: index out of range [10] with length 3)`. Also, instead of terminating, the program keeps running after the panic occurs.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10570456/6680182) it seems that `Println` catches panics from `String()` methods and logs them. How do I prevent this behavior so that 1) my program terminates in the even of a panic in a `String()` method and 2) the full stack-trace of the panic is shown?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {

}

func (foo Foo) String() string {
  var x = "123"
  return fmt.Sprintf("%v", x[10]) // invalid index
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(Foo{})
  fmt.Println("done")
}
```

Comment: You cannot. fmt.Sprintf catches your panic amnd you cannot change this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply print the result of .String()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
}

func (foo Foo) String() string {
    var x = "123"
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", x[10])
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Foo{}.String())
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

Comment: @Pramod https://play.golang.org/p/xFlbSw_jzoK look it displays the panic, which i thought is what OP wanted

Comment: In more complex cases, it looks like `fmt.Sprintf` will also catch panic - is there a fix that doesn't require removing calls to `fmt.Sprintf`?